# Relative path using Uri

Tags: c#, .net

Uri test = new Uri(new Uri("http://www.google.com/test"), "foo");

returns http://www.google.com/foo

but  Uri test = new Uri(new Uri("http://www.google.com/test/"), "foo");

returns http://www.google.com/foo/test

It seems the last slash is very important, is there a unified way to return
http://www.google.com/foo/test in all cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to ensure that your base URI ends with a `/` character:

```
public Uri CombineUris(string baseUri, string relativeUri)
{
    if (!baseUri.EndsWith("/")) {
        baseUri += "/";
    }
    return new Uri(new Uri(baseUri), relativeUri);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to pass the root URI with the trailing `/`. Last slash is very important. Consider `http://www.example.com/foo/bar.html, bar2.html`. It should be resolved to `http://www.example.com/foo/bar2.html`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri test = new Uri(new Uri(GetSafeURIString("http://www.google.com/test")), "foo");



private static string GetSafeURIString(uri)
{
   if(uri == null)
       return uri;
   else
       return uri.EndsWith("/") ? uri : uri + "/";
}
```

Comment: It looks like your `uri != null` condition is inverted.

Comment: null != uri used to be a good practice in the C / C++ world. But, in C# if always expects a boolean and hence no accidental assignment.

Comment: no, I meant you're returning `uri` if it's *not* `null`. I think you want to return it if it *is* `null` :)

Comment: Sorry. Got it. I am updating it.